# Scrutinizer old Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: scrutinizer

I just saw that my Scrutinizer builds runs on Ubuntu 14.04

`scrutinizer@container-0:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty`

Is there a way to use 16.04 or other linux release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer my own question: That's not possible. Scrutinizer's Support team confirmed me that.
If you need to use packages only availables on other Linux version, create a docker container